# Query that returns a multi dimensional collections with a particular criteria

Tags: python, django

Can anyone help me how to query this certain problem?

here is an example model:

```
class Diagnosis(models.Model):
    remarks = models.TextField()
    is_success= models.BooleanField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Here is the implementation:

```
d1 = Diagnosis.objects.create(is_success = False, remarks='d1')
d2 = Diagnosis.objects.create(is_success=False, remarks='d2')
d3 = Diagnosis.objects.create(is_success=True, remarks='d3')
d4 = Diagnosis.objects.create(is_success=False, remarks='d4')
d5 = Diagnosis.objects.create(is_success=False, remarks='d5')
d6 = Diagnosis.objects.create(is_success=False, remarks='d6')
d7 = Diagnosis.objects.create(is_success=True, remarks='d7')
```

Now what i would like to filter is returns a multi dimensional collection(array) from the `is_success=True`  to its previous `is_success=False` that means from d1 to d3 then from d4 to d7 and so on.

I am struggling to get this output example and note that each dict is an instance of `Diagnosis` model:

```
[
   [
       # from the first is_success=False to is_success=True.
       {
           id:1, remarks: 'd1', is_success=False
       },
       {
           id:2, remarks: 'd2', is_success=False
       },
       {
           id:3, remarks: 'd3', is_success=True
       }
   ],  
   [
       # then another row for the same sequence.
       {
           id:4, remarks: 'd4', is_success=False
       },
       {
           id:5, remarks: 'd5', is_success=False
       },
       {
           id:6, remarks: 'd6', is_success=False
       },
       {
           id:7, remarks: 'd7', is_success=True
       }
   ] 
]
```

Comment: what is your expected output? if it is d1(False) you shouldn't because its not function to pass parameters. but still you can create something like this.. do you want to create like this? d1(False)

Comment: The last example below my question that is my expected output sir the (boolean) beside the item is only a detail not exactly what it looks like

Comment: you assigned d1, d2, d3 etc. so you can acheive your output by hardcoded. like "d1({})".format(d1.is_success) is this ok ?

Comment: @User no sir, sorry for not making it clear i updated my question

Comment: d1, d2, d3 etc are assigned variables. you can't fetch it as output .. i got yours but we can print row id from False to True not d1

Comment: yeah not exactly what it is i mean the dN is a Diagnosis instance reference to the variable. ill update my question further.

Comment: You can filter the values of `is_success`, `remarks` and `id` ordered by `id` or `created_at` (whichever you want). And then create the desired multi dimensional collection?

Comment: @sasuke cant get what you mean sir

Comment: What I mean to say is you can retrieve the field values in a particular order from the database and then iterate over it (using `for` or some other loop) and make the multidimensional collection that you want.

Comment: @sasuke you are right i think for loop will be the solution

Comment: So you want to do this just by `filter`? It will only return a queryset. Anyway, you will have to format the queryset to your desired datastructure.

Comment: yeah i thought you can do that using values/group by

Comment: did you try filter between?

Comment: @User didnt try it yet sir

Comment: check my answer @ShiftN'Tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dim = []
row = []
for d in dia_qs:
    row.append(d)
    if d.is_success is True:
        dim.append(row)
        row = []
```

Hope that `dim` is what you want.

Comment: This is what @sasuke talks about haha

Answer (score 0):

try this hope this is exactly what you want,

```
li = []
for i in Diagnosis.objects.all():
    if li:
      for j in li:
        if not j[0] and j[-1]:
          li.insert(li.index(j)+1,[i.is_success])
        else:
          j.append(i.is_success)
    else:
      if not i.is_success:
        li.append([i.is_success])
```